# Windows 10 v1703: Biometric AD authentication without "Hello"

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, biometrics

We are using `Windows 10 Pro Version 1703` at work running on `HP EliteBook 840 G3`.

I have connected a USB fingerprint reader (Suprema BioMini/SFU Slim S20) to my laptop and installed the drivers coming from the manufacturer.

Unfortunately Windows keeps telling me `Windows Hello isn't available on this device`, when looking into the sign-in options. It seems that some preconditions are not met. I have ensured that no GPOs are interfering here.

Interesstingly enough I can log on to the domain using an `HP EliteBook x360` which seems to fully support `Windows Hello`.

Is there another way to use my fingerprint Reader (or another device) without using `Windows Hello` to log on to Active Directory?

**[Edit]**

In my original post I was talking about 'some unmet preconditions'. After some research I found out, that `Windows Hello` requires at least a `Trusted Platform Module` Version of `2.0` to work. My HP EliteBook 840 G3 is only featuring a TPM of version 1.2.

So back to my initial question. How can I use biometric authentication to logon to domain-joined devices without utilizing `Windows Hello`?

Comment: "So back to my initial question. How can I use biometric authentication to logon to domain-joined devices without utilizing Windows Hello?" - Use a third-party solution like you used before Windows Hello was added to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Check and install all available Windows Updates.
2. Go to group policy path: **Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components**. On the right side of the pane, double-click to enable **Allow the use of biometrics**.
3. Update Your Fingerprint Device Driver.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should have added to my initial post, that I have already tried your suggestion without luck.

Comment: Some information is not exact. TPM is not necessary for Windows Hello unless you configure the Windows Hello for Business. And you need add a PIN before you can set up Windows Hello. After that, you will get the 3 sign in options, password, PIN, Fingerprint. You cannot use finger printer without Windows hello.